# Dagger 2 dependency cycle

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I've next problem with injecting ViewModel into fragment:

```
error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public interface FragmentComponent {
       ^
      ...ViewModelFactory is injected at
          ...ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory)
      ...ViewModelFactory is injected at
          ...SplashFragment.viewModelFactory
      ...SplashFragment is injected at
          ...FragmentComponent.inject(ru.syncended.jlocationtracker.auth.fragments.SplashFragment)
```

Where FragmentComponent code:

```
public interface FragmentComponent {
    void inject(SplashFragment splashFragment);
}
```

ViewModelFactory code:

```
private final Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModelProviders;
@Inject
public ViewModelFactory(Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> viewModelProviders) {
    this.viewModelProviders = viewModelProviders;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    Provider<ViewModel> viewModelProvider = viewModelProviders.get(modelClass);
    return (T) viewModelProvider.get();
}
```

ViewModelModule code:

```
@Binds
ViewModelFactory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(SplashViewModel.class)
SplashViewModel bindSplashViewModel(SplashViewModel splashViewModel);
```

And SplashViewModel code:

```
@Inject
public SplashViewModel(IAuthRepository repository) ...
```

How I can to solve that? It's isn't like that it has dependency cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved that problem by next solution:

I changed ViewModelModule code from:

```kotlin
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(SplashViewModel.class)
SplashViewModel bindSplashViewModel(SplashViewModel splashViewModel);
```

To:

```kotlin
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(SplashViewModel.class)
ViewModel bindSplashViewModel(SplashViewModel splashViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Binds
ViewModelFactory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory viewModelFactory);
```

This is a dependency "cycle" of size 1.  It tells Dagger that, in order to get an instance of `ViewModelFactory`, you must first get an instance of `ViewModelFactory` and use that.  This replaces the `@Inject` constructor that would otherwise be used.

To fix this, simply remove this `@Binds` method.  Dagger already knows how to create a `ViewModelFactory` from its `@Inject` constructor.  Alternatively, you can depend on the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` interface instead, and change the `@Binds` method's return type accordingly.